# Xcode HTML to String return nil ?- SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, swift3

```
public func setHtmlBody(_ body: String, bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds) -> String {

    let font = "-apple-system"
    let fontSize = 19
    let fontColor = "#000000"
    let lineHeight = 25
    let imageWidth = bounds.width - 40
    let margin = 20
    let codeStyle = "pre[class*=\"language-\"]{background:white;border-radius:14px;color:black;display:block;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;padding:20px;overflow-x:auto;white-space:pre-wrap;line-height:130%;}pre.language-coffeescript .token.comment{color:#6a7576}pre.language-coffeescript .token.string{color:#8ADC64}pre.language-coffeescript .token.number,pre.language-coffeescript .token.operator{color:#a580f8}pre.language-coffeescript .token.keyword,pre.language-coffeescript .token.class-name,pre.language-coffeescript .token.function{color:#8df}pre.language-swift .token.comment{color:#690}pre.language-swift .token.string{color:#ee433f}pre.language-swift .token.keyword{color:#C945A7}pre.language-swift .token.number,pre.language-swift .token.function,pre.language-swift .token.builtin,pre.language-swift .token.class-name{color:#5C2699}"

    let htmlString = "<style>p, li { font-family:\"\(font)\"; color: \(fontColor); font-size:\(fontSize)px; line-height:\(lineHeight)px } p { margin: \(margin)px 0; } img { max-width: \(imageWidth)px; } #p { font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; line-height: 130%; margin: 50px 20px; } ul li, ol li { margin: 20px 0; font-weight: bold; } \(codeStyle)</style>\(body)"

    return htmlString
}
```

I am using swift 3. Why does the function return me to Nil?

Usign:

```
bodyAttributedString = setHtmlBody(sectionBody).htmlToAttributedString
```

Comment: your function return `String`, not `String?`. So it can't be nil

Comment: bodyAttributedString = setHtmlBody(sectionBody).htmlToAttributedString, in this case, no

Comment: What is `htmlToAttributedString`? That is not a property of `String` in the standard library or Foundation, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the issue with `htmlToAttributedString` function all others working fine. I tried it with a similar method it worked perfectly form me

Please check...

**Extensions** to get html as Attributed string

```
extension Data {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).htmlToAttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

**HTML String building functions**

```
public func setHtmlBody(_ body: String, bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds) -> String {

    let font = "-apple-system"
    let fontSize = 19
    let fontColor = "#000000"
    let lineHeight = 25
    let imageWidth = bounds.width - 40
    let margin = 20
    let codeStyle = "pre[class*=\"language-\"]{background:white;border-radius:14px;color:black;display:block;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;padding:20px;overflow-x:auto;white-space:pre-wrap;line-height:130%;}pre.language-coffeescript .token.comment{color:#6a7576}pre.language-coffeescript .token.string{color:#8ADC64}pre.language-coffeescript .token.number,pre.language-coffeescript .token.operator{color:#a580f8}pre.language-coffeescript .token.keyword,pre.language-coffeescript .token.class-name,pre.language-coffeescript .token.function{color:#8df}pre.language-swift .token.comment{color:#690}pre.language-swift .token.string{color:#ee433f}pre.language-swift .token.keyword{color:#C945A7}pre.language-swift .token.number,pre.language-swift .token.function,pre.language-swift .token.builtin,pre.language-swift .token.class-name{color:#5C2699}"

    let htmlString = "<style>p, li { font-family:\"\(font)\"; color: \(fontColor); font-size:\(fontSize)px; line-height:\(lineHeight)px } p { margin: \(margin)px 0; } img { max-width: \(imageWidth)px; } #p { font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; line-height: 130%; margin: 50px 20px; } ul li, ol li { margin: 20px 0; font-weight: bold; } \(codeStyle)</style>\(body)"
    return htmlString
}
```

**Presentation**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let body = "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>"

    let htmlString = setHtmlBody(body)


    if let attributedString = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString {
        self.labelHTML.attributedText = attributedString
    }
 }
```

**Output**

[image]